# Does React need Flux for one way data flow?

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to **react**. Whether one way data flow in react is achieved only through **flux**(action and store) ?.

```
  <div id="container"></div>

    var Hello = React.createClass({
    changeState: function (event) {
        this.setState({
            sampleState: event.target.value
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            'sampleState': 'World'
        };
    },
    render: function () {

        return ( < div > Hello { this.state.sampleState} 
                    < input onChange ={ this.changeState}> < /input>
                 </div >);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render( < Hello / > ,
document.getElementById('container'));
```

I have changed the state of a component without flux.Does this fall into one way data flow ?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of React's one way data flow is that data goes down the application.

```
  A
 / \
v   v
B   D
|   |
v   v
C   E
```

Component `A` can pass data to Component `B`, which can pass to `C`. Simlarly, `A` can pass to `D` which can pass to `E`.

- Parents components **can** pass data to their children and so on down the component tree.
- Child components **can't** pass data back up to their parents.

Your example doesn't have a directional data flow, because you're only working with one component. The data isn't moving when you change state — it's encapsulated within the component.

```
  A
```

If you added another component to your example and passed properties down to it, you would introduce a one-way, downwards data flow.

```
A
|
v
B
```

The Flux architecture allows you to create cycles in your flow. Data goes down the tree, then out to Flux in the form of an **action**. This action updates a **store**, which in turn updates the components that are subscribed to that store.

```
A  <- [store]
|        ^
v        |
B -> [action]
```

This keeps the data flowing in a single direction. Any component can subscribe to a Flux store, but if that component wants to make meaningful change to a component that is higher than itself in the tree (for instance if `B` wants to change `A`), it must go round in one of these cycles, rather than simply flowing back up the tree.

Comment: @DevendiranKumar If this answer helped you, would you consider marking it as the accepted answer?